# SELECT returns result twice

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

The following code in MariaDB 10.4.13

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE timeout_check()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_timestamp_for_countdown TIME;
    SET var_timestamp_for_countdown = SYSDATE();
    SELECT (SLEEP(2));
    IF (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(SYSDATE()), var_timestamp_for_countdown)) > TIME_TO_SEC(TIME('00:00:01'))) THEN
       SELECT "TIMEOUT EXPIRED";
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL timeout_check();
```

Returns

```
(SLEEP(2))
0
TIMEOUT EXPIRED
TIMEOUT EXPIRED
```

I don't understand:

- why `TIMEOUT EXPIRED` is stated twice;
- where `0` comes from

Thank you

Comment: `0` is the value of `SLEEP(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not returning twice. Each `SELECT` will produce multiple rows of output: the first row is the column headings, the remaining rows are the values that were selected. Since you didn't assign aliases to the expressions that you're selecting, the column headings will be the same as the expressions.

`SELECT (SLEEP(2))` has a column heading `(SLEEP(2))`. The value that it returns is `0`, so that's in the second row of output.

If you don't want to see this result in the output of the call, don't use `SELECT`. You can do

```
SET @ignore = SLEEP(2);
```

`SELECT "TIMEOUT EXPIRED"` has a column heading `TIMEOUT EXPIRED`, and the value it returns is the same string, so that's in the next line of output. If you changed it to something like:

```
SELECT "TIMEOUT EXPIRED" AS error;
```

the output would be:

```
error
TIMEOUT EXPIRED
```